# Need Help with Modulus Algebra

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Non-mathematician here.  I need help solving a formula with a modulus term.

First some background:  I am trying to calculate the hole positions for a dividing head plate, which is a tool used in the field of machining when cutting gears.  The idea is that the user will crank an input handle a certain amount, which will precisely rotate an output shaft holding a metal blank disk to be cut into a gear.  In the photo below, there are 9 concentric rings.  The correct ring is chosen depending on the number of teeth to cut in the blank, and input arm is advanced a calculated number of holes for each gear tooth.  These dividing heads are very expensive, and I am making a home-made one. Thus I have to figure out the positions of the holes.  (Continued below photo)

[image]

In my case, 144 complete turns of the input crank will cause the output to rotate 360 degrees, or 2.5 output degrees per 1 input turn.  I want to create a gear with 42 teeth, which means 8.571428571 degrees/tooth and 3.428571429 turns of the input crank.  This means that I will need to crank 3 full turns, and 0.428571429 additional turns, which is ~154.29 degrees. This means the input arm advances ~154.29 degrees on the dividing plate each time.

The way this usually works is that the dividing head machine has 2 sector arms on the face of the dividing plate (see the bronze arms in the photos).  These would be set to the angle that needs to be advanced each time, ~154.29 degrees in my case. The user starts at the position of one of the arms, and stops at the position of the 2nd arm.

In my example, I created a spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/150kCABqcjefZ4XRDrvqXYC3-MlerWEuJivxFiZAR0QI/edit?usp=sharing) that calculates that the angle of the input arm (and thus the location for the hole) for the first 8 teeth are as follows.  Notice that tooth #8 wraps, and input arm is back to 0 degrees:

```
    tooth    Input arm Degrees    Output Degrees
    1        0.0                  0.00
    2        154.3                8.57  
    3        308.6                17.14
    4        102.9                25.71  
    5        257.1                34.29
    6        51.4                 42.86
    7        205.7                51.43
    8        0.0                  60.00
```

And if I graph these out, I get:

[image]

So what I REALLY want, is the angle between the red dots in the photo.  When I have this, I can generate the dividing plate I need.  So I am going to try to write all this in some formulas.  But here I am getting lost...

The formula for input turns **I** (units: turns) to achieve output degrees **O** (units: degrees) in a machine with a conversion **C** (units: turns/degree)  =

```
O = I / C

O is Output, in degrees
I is Input, in full turns
C is Conversion factor, in turns/degree
```

Since the input arm is wrapping, this would involve a modulus operation. In my example, I calculate 7 different angles before the 8th operation returns the input handle back to position of 0 degrees.  Thus there are 7 red dots on the image above, and the angle between each dot is:

```
Angle between red dots = 360 / 7
```

But how to determine this value of **7** without using an iterative algorithm such as a spreadsheet??

$$\frac{360\ output\ deg}{42\ tooth} * \frac{1\ input\ turn}{2.5\ output\ deg} * \frac{360\ input\ deg}{1\ input\ turn} = 1234.28571\ \frac{input\ deg}{tooth}$$

$$Modulus(1234.28571\ deg,\ 360\ deg) = 154.285714285714286\ deg$$

$$Modulus(154.285714285714286*N,\ 360) = 0$$

In my case N = 7.  But how to calculate this, i.e for different cases when cutting gears with different number of teeth?

tl;dr

if Modulus(C*n, 360) = 0, how to calculate value of N.  I understand that there are multiples of N that will also work.  I just want the first value.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $154.\overline{285714} = \frac{1080}{7}$. Then, we wish to find values of $N$ such that:

$$\text{Modulus}(\frac{1080N}{7}, 360) = 0$$

This happens if and only if $\frac{1080N}{7} = 360k$ for some (positive in your application) integer $k$. Then:

$$N = \frac{7\cdot 360k}{1080} = \frac{7}{3}k$$

Thus, the smallest value of $N$, which happens at $k=1$, is $\boxed{\frac{7}{3}}.$

In general, the smallest value of $N$ is $\frac{360}{C}$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Questions: How would I know to convert ~154.2857 into 1080/7?  I.e. in other cases?  Also, you give me a fractional value for N (7/3).  But in my example, I found the angle between red dots as 360/7 after I found N=7.  But if N=7/3, that would give a different result.  So I'm confused by that.  For my situation, and I just looking for integer values?  And if so, I'm back to not knowing how to solve this.  Thanks again for your time.

Comment: For your second question, converting to a modulus equation may introduce extraneous solutions that solve the modulus equation but do not solve the original problem because of all the possible multiples of $N$.